# Get values from a document recursively

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following structure of the MongoDB database record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd569eb628243119cd933f5"),
    "Name" : "Parent555",
    "hash" : "Q2Nj1nGtGJCkHT6eygg1L0OrprQkhGd846fdd5",
    "child_info" : {
        "Name" : "Child_one",
        "hash" : "2ac616b42d846fdd52002dc9ad7d810f9f8ce9",
        "child_info" : {
            "Name" : "Child_two",
            "hash" : "5cd9119ae60a0a58d38999468648c371c50b7a"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a query to aggregate all hashes recursively from the record to make the result look like that?

```
{
    "Parent555":{
        "Q2Nj1nGtGJCkHT6eygg1L0OrprQkhGd846fdd5",
        "2ac616b42d846fdd52002dc9ad7d810f9f8ce9",
        "5cd9119ae60a0a58d38999468648c371c50b7a"
    }
}
```

There might be 4 or 5 nested child, that's why I'm interested in a recursive way of doing it.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to `jQuery` and `Postgresql`

Comment: I think, if you will use this type of schema, then it will be difficult to store and retrieve documents. How about storing the documents with the fields `parent`, `child`? Something like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/34W7jyCtVt/)?

Comment: This is a good idea, totally worth to think it over. Unfortunately, I have to deal with such a structure.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider my comment:

> I think, if you will use this type of schema, then it will be difficult to store and retrieve documents. How about storing the documents with the fields `parent`, `child`? Something like this?

```
{
    "parentName" : "Parent555",
    "hash" : "Q2Nj1nGtGJCkHT6eygg1L0OrprQkhGd846fdd5",
    "childName" : "Child_one"
},
{
    "parentName" : "Child_one",
    "hash" : "2ac616b42d846fdd52002dc9ad7d810f9f8ce9",
    "childName" : "Child_two"
},
{
    "parentName" : "Child_two",
    "hash" : "5cd9119ae60a0a58d38999468648c371c50b7a"
}
```

The above schema is somewhat easy for retrieving and storing queries, as we may not to keep on nesting. If, you are bound with your schema, then, this will be helpful for others.

Considering the above collection, [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) will be very helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$childName",
      connectFromField: "childName",
      connectToField: "parentName",
      as: "child_hash"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "parentName": "Parent555"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      parentName: 1,
      hash: 1,
      child_hash: {
        $map: {
          input: "$child_hash",
          as: "c",
          in: "$$c.hash"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
  "child_hash": [
    "5cd9119ae60a0a58d38999468648c371c50b7a",
    "2ac616b42d846fdd52002dc9ad7d810f9f8ce9"
  ],
  "hash": "Q2Nj1nGtGJCkHT6eygg1L0OrprQkhGd846fdd5",
  "parentName": "Parent555"
}
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qB_6cgpVfdR)